# Parent element selector using pure CSS

Tags: css

What is the way of getting parent element using pure CSS. Am using VS 2013, So it must be css3. I have seen in google about has() and < selectors. Unfortunately they do not work.

Comment: The fact that they do not work should be a clue. Also, your version of Visual Studio has absolutely no bearing on what level of CSS, or what CSS standard at all, you can use - the statement "[I am] using VS 2013, So it must be css3." is simply absurd.

Answer (score -3):

There is parent selector in css4 [`$E > F`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/) (last in table) where `$E` is parent of `F`. Unfortunately there is no support for it ([only 26%](http://css4-selectors.com/browser-selector-test/) for whole css4).

Comment: The $ syntax has been gone for years. You're quoting the FPWD as canon. [Don't ever do that.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#status) (And what is "whole css4" even supposed to mean?)